# UIButton bad touch area after change position

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, storyboard

I have a problem. I am working on app and I am using Storyboard(AutoLayout off). For iPhone 5 and later it is good. But for iPhone 4S I have to change position programatically. But after change I cant click on UIButton, it doesnt change touch area. Where can be the problem? Or how you solve problems with screen size?

Thank you

Comment: How are you changing the position of it? Also, why? Are you not using auto layout? This should remove any need to move the button in code.

Comment: Add your code please. Mostly in this kind problem is caused by view depth. Check another view is not on your button.

Comment: This is my code for changing position. When I set autolayout on and set bottom space. There is same bug. `self.AddPartnerButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.AddPartnerButton.frame.origin.x, heightScreen-100, self.AddPartnerButton.frame.size.width, self.AddPartnerButton.frame.size.height);`